# How to replace string in files recursively via sed or awk?

Tags: linux, macos, awk, sed

I would like to know how to **search from the command line** for a string in various files of type .rb.

And **replace**:

```
.delay([ANY OPTIONAL TEXT FOR DELETION]).
```

with

```
.delay.
```

Besides sed an awk are there any other command line tools included in the OS that are better for the task?

**Status**

So far I have the following regular expression:

```
.delay\(*.*\)\.
```

I would like to know how to match only the expression ending on the first closing parenthesis? And avoid replacing:

```
.delay([ANY OPTIONAL TEXT FOR DELETION]).sometext(param)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to find and replace text in files - `sed` seems to be the best command line solution.

Search for a string in the text file and replace:

```
sed -i 's/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/' file.name
```

Or, if you need to process multiple occurencies of `PATTERN` in file, add `g` key

```
sed -i 's/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/g' file.name
```

For multiple files processing - redirect list of files to sed:

```
echo "${filesList}" | xargs sed -i ...
```

Comment: redirecting a list of files like that to sed will just have sed operate on that list, rather than the files themselves.  Try `echo hello | sed s/hello/goodbye/`.

Comment: Thanks for fixing that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` to generate your list of files, and `xargs` to run `sed` over the result:

```
find . -type f -print | xargs sed -i 's/\.delay.*/.delay./'
```

`find` will generate a list of files contained in your current directory (`.`, although you can of course pass a different directory), `xargs` will read that list and then run `sed` with the list of files as an argument.

Instead of `find`, which here generates a list of *all* files, you could use something like `grep` to generate a list of files that contain a specific term.  E.g.:

```
grep -rl '\.delay' | xargs sed -i ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For the part of the question where you want to only match and replace until the first `)` and not include a second pair of `()`, here is how to change your regex:

```
.delay\(*.*\)\.
```

->

```
\.delay\([^\)]*\)
```

I.e. match "actual dot, delay, brace open, everything but brace close and brace close".

E.g. using sed:

```
>echo .delay([ANY OPTIONAL TEXT FOR DELETION]).sometext(param) | sed -E "s/\.delay\([^\)]*\)/.delay/"
```

> .delay.sometext(param)

I recommend to use grep for finding the right files:

```
grep -rl --include "*.rb" '\.delay' .
```

Then feed the list into xargs, as recommended by other answers.

Credits to the other answers for providing a solution for feeding multiple files into sed.